# Word2Vec.wv.most_similar() gives unexpected results

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk, word2vec

I'm creating a predictive text python program using Word2Vec and I'm having trouble building an accurate Word2Vec model.

If it's relevant, my sample text is "Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde". I've tried building the model with and without stopwords and neither has given a reasonable output to the most_similar function.

```py
def clean_text(text):
         text = text.lower()

         #removing punctuation except for ./!/?
         text = re.sub('[^\w\s.!?]', '', text)

         return(text)

text = open("book.txt")
text = text.read()
text = clean_text(text)

#convert data into nested list of sentences which are lists of words
data = [word_tokenize(sentence) for  sentence in sent_tokenize(text)]

#vectorize
word2vec = Word2Vec(data)
embed()
```

Once embed starts the console, I play around with word2vec.wv.most_similar() and get nonsensical results.

For example, the top match for "doubt" is "." and the top match for "hyde" is "as". For "hyde", I would expect it to come up with another character's name as I imagine they would all be used in similar ways.

Comment: I think the problem lies in the model training. The nonsensical results are due to the placement of texts. For example, I believe that the data in text.txt contains "Mr." and "Dr." etc. These punctuation marks are a part of the title. Clubbing them might work.

Comment: From what I've seen, nltk's sentence tokenizer accounts for terms like "Mr.", "Dr.", etc. -- they're in the Word2Vec vocabulary as singular terms, and as such, I can't see how they would interfere with the model training.

Comment: How many texts & words are in your data? What do you see if you enable `INFO` level-logging? Can you show some of the results you consider nonsensical? Are you sure `text` is what you expect it to be after each step? (It may be helpful to avoid clobbering the prior value in place, and use a new descriptive variable name each step, and print some stats/excerpts about the corpus after each step.)